# This Exception comes while install tensorflow 1.3.0

Tags: tensorflow

i am getting this error while installing tensorflow 1.3.0. in the terminal of mac

```
Installing collected packages: tensorflow-tensorboard, backports.weakref, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: tensorflow-tensorboard 0.4.0rc3
    Uninstalling tensorflow-tensorboard-0.4.0rc3:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-tensorboard-0.4.0rc3
Exception:
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 97, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports/weakref.py'

Comment: have you tried installing it with administrator privileges?

Comment: no,does it need admin privileges?

Comment: Probably, the error says "Permission denied"